# Volume of an n-simplex (Without Probabilities)

Tags: calculus, general-topology, geometry

Compute the volume of
$$
S_n=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n},x_i\geq 0,\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} x_i<1\}
$$

I don't really have an idea how to solve it.

My 'work':
Perhaps I could use 
$$
||x||_1=|x_1|+...+|x_n|
$$
So the set is 
$$
S_n=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n},x_i\geq 0,B(0,1)\}
$$
Where
$$
B(0,1)=\left\{M\in\mathbb{R^n} \,\mid\,d(M,0)<1\right\}
$$
But I don't see where it leads me...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried it for some small $n$, there might be an interesting pattern there... Although I'm not sure...

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume

Comment: do want to know using calculus?

Comment: @janmarqz yes:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V_n$ denote the (as-yet unknown) volume of $S_n$. If $S_n(t)$ denotes the simplex $$
S_n(t) = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) : x_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \leq t\},
$$
so that $S_n(1)$ is your $S_n$, then the volume of $S_n(t)$ is $V_n t^n$. (Proof: Scale $S_n$ by a factor of $t$.)

Slicing $S_n$ by the hyperplane $x_n = t$ with $0 \leq t \leq 1$ gives (a translated copy of) $S_{n-1}(1 - t)$ as cross section. Cavalieri's theorem allows you to express $V_n$ recursively in terms of $V_{n-1}$, and this recursion is almost trivial to solve in closed form.

Comment: @Julien The two simplices have the same volume: Their difference is a bounded portion of the hyperplane $\sum_i x_i = 1$, which has ($n$-dimensional) volume zero. :)